# Get frame that accessory of a UITableViewCell will have for HeightForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, uitableview, layout, accessoryview

When iOS calls HeightForRowAtIndexPath, it presumably wants to know the height that my cell will have. If my cell has an accessory, this creates a problem. The system decides where to put the accessory, and I will position everything around it. So to compute the height, I need to know where the accessory is going to be. But even if I know the accessoryType, I don't know that yet, because I don't have the cell yet, and iOS will position the accessory.

Is there a way around this problem?